# How to implement a #define in another #define?

Tags: c++, macros

**The previous problem description was ambiguous, so I modified something below. Thanks.**

I want to implement some macros like this:

```
#define AddVariable(x) \
    #define x (++counter)

class Base {
 private:
  int counter = 0;
}

class Extend : public Base {
 public:
  void Handler() {
    AddVariable(ASDF);
    AddVariable(HJKL);
    // Here may add more variables.
  }
  void AnotherHandler() {
    // It calls ASDF, HJKL too.
  }
}
```

The ASDF and HJKL should be available through all handlers in the cpp file, so I have to define it in the macro (it's not a good design, though). But how should I write the proper macros to achieve it (#define cannot be nested in another #define)? Or is there another better way of implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Update:

A potential implementation is

```
#define AddVariable(x) \
  int x = ++counter;
```

It works, but x is not global, and I have to fix this.

Comment: What is `AddVariable` supposed to do?

Comment: `#define ASDF ++counter` will not do what you want anyway

Comment: The preprocessor is a *compile-time* thing, and is handled as a separate step before the actual compilation, therefore you can't do anything using the preprocessor during runtime.

Comment: Please don't do this..

Comment: This looks like an [x-y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I assume you could chain #defines in *different* preprocessor directives. I always get confused with it so I'd just go and experiment, if in doubt with gcc -E.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg seems to have a (better?) idea of what you are trying to achieve at all. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Is there any reason `int const ABCD = ++counter;` can't be used?  (Of course, `ABCD` will _not_ be a constant integral expression in this case.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I want it to be flexible. If we have another class that extends the Base class, we may add new variables in the new class.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I realized that, but is there a better way to keep flexible in the subclass which extends the Base class and is able to add its own variables?

Comment: @AntonSavin The subclass which extends the Base class may add its own variables.

Comment: What are the lifetimes/scopes of `ASDF`/`HJKL` supposed to be? Are they supposed to be members of `Base`? Globals in your cpp? What calls `AnotherHandler()`?

Comment: @szefany And...  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @AtlasC1 Sorry for the ambiguous description. I've updated the problem, it might be a bit clearer now.

Comment: @JamesKanze Actually the added variables stands for some states, each with a specific handler (we may use a map as a reflection). That is, in the subclass we are allowed to add new states and new handlers rather than in the base class. But the variables should be shared so that they can be called in different handlers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166337/does-c-support-compile-time-counters

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to expose an incrementer to a `Base` object's `counter` to all of your functions in the .cpp file.

**Answer: This is not possible.**

The other functions/objects in your .cpp file do not have a reference to a `Base` object and thereby cannot change any of it's data.

If you want to maintain a *single* counter for all the `Base` objects you might try something like this:

```
class Base {
public:
    static void ASDF(){counter++;}
private:
    static int counter = 0;
};
```

This can be called from and other function:

```
void AnotherHandler() {
    Base::ASDF();
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
class Base {
protected:
    static int counter = 0;
};

class Another : public Base{
public:
    Another(){
        counter++; // As a child of Base you have access to all of it's protected variables
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the counter belongs to the object itself. I don't need a static one.

Comment: @szefany Is there a reason you wouldn't just make `counter` `protected`?

Answer (score 1):

Would using an `std::map` work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class Base {
protected:

    void AddVariable(const std::string& name) {
        variables[name] = counter++;
    }

    int& GetVariable(const std::string& name) {
        return variables[name];
    }

private:
    int counter = 0;
    std::map<std::string, int> variables;
};

class Extend : Base {
public:

    void Handler() {
        AddVariable("ASDF");
        AddVariable("HJKL");
        // May add more variables here ...
    }

    void AnotherHandler() {
        // Use ASDF, HJKL here too
        std::cout << GetVariable("ASDF") << std::endl;
        std::cout << GetVariable("HJKL") << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Extend e;
    e.Handler();
    e.AnotherHandler();
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Comment: I guess "Add" in the question doesn't really mean "add"; it rather means "increase" (add 1 to the value of the variable); I don't know for sure though; seems vague.

Comment: @anatolyg It's "add" indeed; the codes here might be a bit ambiguous. It should be "adding a new constant variable/label assigned to a specific value", and that value is controlled by the increasing counter.

Comment: @szefany Does my modified answer better suit your needs? If not, what else does it need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that (defining a macro in a macro) with the C preprocessor.

However, sometimes you could play [X-macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) tricks, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27336172/841108).

If you really need macro defining macros, switch to some external or non-standard preprocessor, like [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) or [gpp](http://en.nothingisreal.com/wiki/GPP).

Alternatively, generate your C++ code with some external tool (e.g. your own Python or GNU awk script)

At last, recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. GNU [cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/)) or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) offer the [`__COUNTER__`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros) macro (also usable indirectly with [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification) & [concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation))